# Functions and try() in R

Tags: r, error-handling

Still struggling with R, especially with error handling:

If I use:

```
result <- try(sqlSave(ch,df,tablename="tblTest"))
```

I can use:

```
if (class(result) != "try-error")
```

to check if something went wrong. No problem.

But if I use `try` in combination with a function it doesn't work as I expected:

```
 result <- try(ch<-odbcConnect("TEST"))
```

gives "-1" for `result` and "integer" for `class(result)`

So should I use

```
ch<-odbcConnect("TEST")
if (ch != -1)
```

and use `geterrmessage()` for the error message?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you read closely error message you could see that `odbcConnect` gives you warning. Error is generated by ODBC drivers and it isn't error in `try` meaning (`geterrmessage()` won't work either).

You could use `tryCatch` to handle this, e.g.:

```
tryCatch(odbcConnect("TEST"), warning=function(w) print("FAIL!"))
```

---

Some more explanation:
-1 is a result of `odbcDriverConnect` function. If you look at the code there are lines

```
stat <- .Call(C_RODBCDriverConnect, as.character(connection), 
        id, as.integer(believeNRows), as.logical(readOnlyOptimize))
if (stat < 0L) {
     warning("ODBC connection failed")
     return(stat)
}
```

So you end without errors (and with a warning) and with integer code from C-level. Actually this code is returned when connection is succeed too (but then is equal 1). **When there is no errors then result class can't be `try-error`**.
It is not problem with `try` and functions but specific of this particular function (`odbcDriverConnect`).

You could of course use this behaviour as in your example

```
ch <- odbcConnect("TEST")
if (ch != -1)
```

With `tryCatch` you could do

```
tryCatch(ch<-odbcConnect("TEST"), warning=function(w) print("FAIL!"))
```

which creates `ch` variable when succeed and print message when failed.
Or

```
ch <- tryCatch(odbcConnect("TEST"), warning=function(w) {print("FAIL!");return(NA)})
```

which always creates `ch` variable but in case of failure there is `NA` value.

Comment: But still I don't understand why class(result) give "integer" with a function call and otherwise "try-error".

And where do I store the channel variable of odbcConnect in your example?

Comment: Just one question: Why doesn't -- df <- tryCatch(sqlQuery(ch,paste("SELECT * FROM tblTest")), warning=function(w) {print("FAIL!");return(NA)}) -- work the same? I don't get a printed warning and "df" contains the error message not a "NA" value

Comment: Cause in case of error you should write function to handle it. So you should do: `df <- tryCatch(sqlQuery(ch,paste("SELECT * FROM tblTest")),warning=function(w) {print("FAIL! (warning)");return(NA)},error=function(e) {print("FAIL! (error)");return(NA)})`

Comment: Still no printed error message. Something to do with "options" or something?

Comment: Change `error` function to print message if you want this: `error=function(e) {print(geterrormessage());print("FAIL! (error)");return(NA)}`.

Comment: I've now two pieces of code: `ch <- tryCatch(odbcConnect("TEST"), warning=function(w) {print("FAIL! (warning)");return(NA)}, error=function(e) {print(paste("ERROR:",geterrmessage()));return(NA)})`
and
`df <- tryCatch(sqlQuery(ch,"SELECT * FROM tblTest"), warning=function(w) {print("FAIL! (warning)");return(NA)}, error=function(e) {print(paste("ERROR:",geterrmessage()));return(NA)})`. odbcConnect works fine with errors and warnings, sqlQuery only with errors :-(

Comment: I'll ask a separate question about this

Comment: So `try` doesn't catch warnings? Then how do you catch warnings?