# RODBC functions and errors/warnings

Tags: r, rodbc

A question about this R code:

```
library(RODBC)

ch <- tryCatch(odbcConnect("RTEST"),
  warning=function(w){print("FAIL! (warning)");return(NA)},
  error=function(e){print(paste("ERROR:",geterrmessage()));return(NA)})

df <- tryCatch(sqlQuery(ch,"SELECT Test from tblTest"),
  warning=function(w){print("FAIL! (warning)");return(NA)},
  error=function(e){print(paste("ERROR:",geterrmessage()));return(NA)})

odbcClose(ch)
```

Code works fine for errors (forced by omitting the required paramaters in the code) in both cases (warning- and error part are almost exactly the same): I get a NA value and an errormessage.

Also for an error with sqlQuery (give an invalid DSN): NA value and an errormessage.

But not for warnings with sqlQuery. No message output, but `df` contains the message (so no NA). Why?

Comment: Sorry, I posted the first part to quick. Edited now

Comment: I haven't access to database for few days, so I cannot answer to comments [in your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440373/functions-and-try-in-r).

Comment: No problem, you answered my question for 95%, the remaining part is covered in this question. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked code for `sqlQuery` and found this:

```
stat <- odbcQuery(channel, query, rows_at_time)
if (stat == -1L) {
    if (errors) 
        return(odbcGetErrMsg(channel))
    else return(invisible(stat))
}
```

`error` is parameter to `sqlQuery`, on default `TRUE`, so it gives you character vector without error or warning. If you change it to `sqlQuery(ch,"SELECT Test from tblTest",FALSE)` then `df` will contain `-1` value. This is error code from C-level, but not error in R meaning so `tryCatch` could not handle it.

I suppose that you need to check if `df==-1` after `tryCatch`.

Comment: Thanks. So if I add the `errors=FALSE` part and deletes the warning function part I can detect errors by checking for the NA value and warnings by checking for a -1 value. It works, but I'd rather seen one approach for handling errors and warning but I think it isn't possible

Comment: You could leave warning part in case you got actual "R-warning". `-1` value gives information that something went wrong on C-level part of odbc connection.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this code. Now I can handle the specific Mysql error_code:

```
saveText <- function(query, channel, errors = TRUE) {
  stat <- odbcQuery(channel, query)
  if (stat == -1L) {
    if (errors)
      err <- odbcGetErrMsg(channel)
    else {
      err <- invisible(stat)
    }
    return(err)
  }
}
```