# R shiny crashed even after trycatch()

Tags: r

Below is the part of my server code. Actually there is an error in SQL for some conditions. So when I execute in R calling SQL, the R shiny crashes. So i tried putting `trycatch()`. Even then the app crashes but I can see notifications when app crashes. Please anyone help

```
if(input$ID != "" && !is.null(input$Date)){

      # to get data from SQL
      tryCatch({
      # to get data from SQL
      sql <- paste0("SELECT * FROM [SSS].[AAA].[CCC]")
      df1 <- sqlQuery(db, sql)   # db is already declared
        },

      error = function(err){
        showNotification(paste0(err), type = 'err')
      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to do `df1 <- sqlQuery(db, sql, errors=FALSE)`, which should return -1; you could then check `df1 != -1` before continuing in your code.

edit:
You could do something like:

```
myReactiveFun <- reactive({
  shiny::req(input$Date)
  sql <- paste0("SELECT * FROM [SSS].[AAA].[CCC]")
  df1 <- sqlQuery(db, sql, errors=FALSE) 
  shiny::validate(shiny::need( df1 != -1, "need valid SQL query result...")

})
```

Comment: yes i got. but I get notification now. But it the original message and not what is there in "Show notification". May I know why?

Comment: Also can we copy sql error messages to ````show notification````

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501528/rodbc-functions-and-errors-warnings for a way to do that

Comment: Feel free to mark the question as answered if this answered it.