# Does anyone know the equivalent of panel.lmlineq and panel.text (from lattice) in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation, lattice, lm

I have the following toy example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
library ("lattice")
library ("latticeExtra")
data (iris)
xyplot(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length | Species, data = iris, panel = function(x, y, ...) { 
        panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
        panel.lmlineq(x, y, adj = c(1,0), 
            lty = 1,col.text='red', pos= 4,
            col.line = "blue", digits = 1,r.squared =TRUE)
        panel.text(7, 4, round(cor(x, y),3), font=2, adj=c(0.5,-0.6))
        panel.text(7, 4, round(cor.test(x,y)$p.value, 3), font=1, adj=c(0.5,0.6))},
xlab = "Sepal.Length", ylab = "Sepal_Width")
```

[image]

So, as you can see, I have a data frame with levels (`Species`) that I'd like to plot (all at the same time) showing their regression line with the R-squared value and also printing their `cor()` and `cor.test()` outputs. Preferably, in an aesthetically pleasing manner.

Has anyone tried to do something similar?  Is there an efficient way to do it?

Comment: Probably one of the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7549694/324364) will be the best you can do.

Comment: For the regression line, `+ geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do things like this using the `tidyverse` [workflow](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/), with help from the `ggplot2` extension `ggpmisc`.  There is a lot of room for customization, and you can minimize or streamline things if you wish.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(ggpmisc)

analysis <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .)),
    cor = map(data, ~tidy(cor.test(.x$Sepal.Length, .x$Sepal.Width), 3)))

stats <- analysis %>%
  unnest(cor)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  geom_text(data = stats, aes(label = sprintf("r = %s", round(estimate, 3)), x = 7, y = 4)) +
  geom_text(data = stats, aes(label = sprintf("p = %s", round(p.value, 3)),  x = 7, y = 3.8)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x) +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~~")),
               formula = y ~ x,
               parse = TRUE) +
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

[image]

Comment: The code is clever. However, with my own data, I have a small problem. I'd like to ask whether is possible to include an if statement in the cor.test. There's a group among my observations, let's say it would be (virginica) that, in my data, has 2 observations only, so the cor.test returns = not enough finite observations. In your experience, would it be possible to prevent this from stopping the whole process?

Comment: You could write a wrapper around `cor.test` to do that.

Comment: I am not very advanced in R. I've seen these possible answers 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156856/ddply-cor-test-with-error-handling
But I can't extract the correct values to be passed to the map 

    group_cor2 <- function(DF, x , y) {
      check <- try(cor.test(DF[,x], DF[,y])$estimate, silent = TRUE)
      if(class(check) == "try-error")
        return(data.frame(cor = NA))
      return(data.frame(cor = cor.test(DF[,x], DF[,y])$estimate))
      return(data.frame(cor = cor.test(DF[,x], DF[,y])$p.value))
    }

Comment: You could simply check if the rows of the data are greater than 2.  If it's less, return a warning, if it's equal or greater, proceed to the cor.test.  Don't store the output, and it will return the cor.test results.